# Elixir - What is syntax for function definitions?

Tags: elixir

Using Elixir V1.1.1 on OS X I am having problems getting my head around the Elixir function definition syntax.

Given a function definition:

```
def foobar(arg1, arg2), do: <<something>> end
```

It seems that in some cases the comma  after the parenthesis is required, other times it is not. Likewise the colon after the 'do' and likewise the closing 'end'. I am sure I am vastly over-complicating the situation, but this seems like a weird setup for a programming language.

Under what circumstances are these elements required/optional?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've combined two forms of method definition there - the shorter one-line syntax and the longer `do`/`end` syntax.

If you have a one-line method, you can write like the following:

`def foobar(foo, bar), do: baz`

Note the comma, and no `end`.

If you have a multi-line method, the syntax is slightly different:

```
def foobar(foo, bar) do
  foo
  bar
end
```

Note no comma and the placement of the `end`.

Both types are described here: http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/modules.html#named-functions (note the long form for `Math.zero?/1`, and the shorter form under the 'Function capturing' heading)

Comment: It's a shame that the Elixir syntax seems to be almost completely specified by example, rather than by using a formal syntax definition language. Oh for a bit of BNF, or even Railroad Normal Form :-)

Comment: @Andy It's open source.  I'm sure they would welcome a document spelling out the BNF for the syntax.

Comment: A very good point. I've got the Xmas break coming up, maybe I'll take a stab at one.

Comment: The "end" is completely unnecessary in the functional context, try to clean them and read again the code, really more clean and beautiful.