# Is there a way to directly return a value from a tuple in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

Given a function that returns a tuple, is there a way to pluck and return a particular value from that tuple on the same line? I often find myself using this pattern in Elixir, and was wondering if there's a shorthand way of achieving the same result.

For example, I'm plucking and returning `result` in the function below:

```
def foo() do
  {:ok, result} = get_result()
  result
end
```

Is there a way to eliminate the need for the second line of code in that method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The typical way to handle this would be to use [`Kernel.SpecialForms.with/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#with/1):

```rb
def foo(), do: with {:ok, result} <- get_result(), do: result
```

This approach has many advantages, besides it’s clean succinct notation. It will propagate `:error` (and anything that does not match `{:ok, _}`) *through*, making error handling a charm.

Whether you want to discard any not-ok input and return just `:error`, use `else` clause with `with`:

```rb
def foo(), do: with {:ok, result} <- get_result(), do: result, else: (_ -> :error)
```

To mimic the *exact* behaviour of the initial code (raise `MatchError` on not-ok):

```rb
def foo(), do: with {:ok, result} <- get_result(), do: result, else: (42 = :error)
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use `elem/2` to get the second item of a term:

```
def foo() do
  get_result() |> elem(1)
end
```

but this will not assert that the first element of the tuple is `:ok` like your original code will. If you want to assert that as well, you can define and reuse a simple function:

```
def foo do
  get_result() |> extract()
end

def extract({:ok, term}), do: term
def extract(_), do: :error # raise an error here if you want
```

Answer (score 1):

#### you can code golf it in one line:

```
def foo, do: get_result |> (&(elem(&1,0) == :ok && elem(&1,1) || :error)).()
```

---

more details about the several syntactic sugars that are used here:

- write a function in [one line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33983483/7852283)
- stream result of first function into first argument of a second function: `fun1() |> fun2()`
- create an anonymous function with one argument using this syntax:
  `(&()).()`
- simulate a ternary condition:

  `A && B || C` is the same as `if A do B else C end`

It is a fancy way to **code golf** in elixir. However, you lose in readability.

Comment: Oneliner doing absolutely the same might be much less ugly: `def foo(), do: with {:ok, result} <- get_result(), do: result, else: (_ ->  :error)`.

Comment: You have shown me a nicer solution. However, I like the fact that there is a hack to stream into an anonymous function.